# Way to quickly open and re-save all PDF files in a folder?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, pdf-reader, print-to-pdf

I have 40 PDF forms that were filled. When I compile the form responses (using the "Export Data From Multiple Forms" option) I often see in the consolidated file that some entered responses are either missing completely or partially incomplete. Reading online this seems to be a common problem unfortuntately.

To remedy this issue I want to re-save every single PDF form in my folder and replace the existing file. That is, I want to to File->"Save As PDF" and "Replace Existing File" for every PDF in my folder.

How can I re-save all my files within having to do it one by one?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you have a copy of each PDF which has the correct information filled out? Or do you need to manually re-enter the information, and then overwrite the existing one?

Comment: In other words, what process do you have now that you want to change?

Comment: I have all forms with the correct information filled in. Sometimes the PDF form will open and display the correct info, other times it won't. To remedy this, I want to open every filled form and *re-save* it.

Comment: @jpaugh any tips?

Comment: I can't offer a quick solution, but perhaps a new, productive line of thought: If the PDFs have all the correct information, but opening them doesn't always work, I'm skeptical that re-saving them makes a difference. (In other words, it means they're being read incorrectly.) If re-saving really does fix it, that implies that they're getting saved in a different internal format than they had before, something that "works better."

Comment: If you could identify what changes are necessary, you could (perhaps) use a command-line tool to replicate them. Something like ghostscript, or [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/), which works on linux, at least. The upshot of this approach is, you become much more familiar with the PDF format, and it's not guaranteed that you'll find a tool which does what you want, unless Adobe offers some command-line option.

Comment: The other option I see is to replicate your current procedure in an automated fashion. Since you have some programming background, I think the effort of learning to do this with [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) would be similar to what it would take to do it 40 times by hand, especially if you use something like [Pulover's Macro Creator](https://www.macrocreator.com/) to generate an AHK script to get you started. The upshot is, you gain experience with a general GUI-manipulating tool, which can help you with other projects, too.